GitHub briefly closed the SmokeDetector repo - what exactly happened?
On Tuesday, September 3, 2024, around 15:05 UTC, GitHub sent out email notifications to SmokeDetector and all users who had a fork of the repository, notifying us that it had been disabled because of an unspecified Terms of Service violation.
We quickly filled in the appeal form (I did personally on the behalf of Charcoal, and I know many owners of forks did on their part) and services were restored yesterday Sep 4 around 7:45 UTC.
Beyond that, we don't know what happened. I am posting this as an announcement, but to make it a proper question, I'm inviting answers with authoritative information about this event (or, in the worst case, I will eventually self-answer with "we just don't know" if nothing else happens).
Please don't post speculative answers. We want this to be facts-based. (I can't and don't want to try to regulate what people post in comments, though.)
In some more detail, SmokeDetector operations continued throughout the incident with reduced flexibility. In other words, the code continued to work, but we were unable to update it with new patterns, like we otherwise do hundreds of times per day.
As background, Charcoal is a volunteer organization who attempt to flag spam, automatically where feasible, to keep the Stack Exchange network reasonably spam-free. The centerpiece of this effort is SmokeDetector, a program which scans new or edited posts (questions and answers on any Stack Exchange site) for various words and patterns which we develop over time to identify possible spam.
The system crucially depends on sharing our code on GitHub, where the various tooling and APIs around pull requests and CI/CD help keep things running smoothly.
Our sincere thanks to all volunteers across the wider network and personnel at Stack Exchange, Inc. who chipped in and tried to apply pressure on GitHub, or just voiced your appreciation for our efforts. We obviously can't know what changed GitHub's minds, either, but the support so many of you expressed during this incident was extremely encouraging and helpful.

It's worth adding that adguard's filter repos went down around the same time

I'm hesitant to roll back here, but [tag:support] seems counter-intuitive for the topic here; that's why I chose [tag:discussion]. If the guidance for these tags makes it this hard to decide, perhaps that guidance should be reviewed instead.

Oh, I see the problem with the guidance. It was revised by Sonic to add in "or question with a concrete answer". That's not correct, and was invented out of whole cloth. There is no precedent in either how the tag has historically been used/applied, or in the revision history, to substantiate that addition. And it's not even mentioned in the revision comment that this substantive change was made; the comment makes it sound like only grammar was edited, which would not include adding new rules.

There's more context on the meta discord, but it was posted in the channel that's not supposed to be copied out.

@CodyGray I made the edit to the wiki based on an answer to the FAQ on how Meta.SE works, which since many years before I registered for the network stated that the [tag:discussion] tag was for soliciting opinions, and the usage I'd seen for [tag:support] in asking questions about how site features work. I thought it was correct because I didn't have the rep to make binding tag wiki edits yet and my edit was approved. That said, I now understand the correct usage and won't push it any further.

I do, however, believe that there is sufficient value in using the tags to clearly indicate whether one is looking for opinions vs. factual answers. Makyen has said before that required tags imply a question's intent (and in fact deleted one of my MSO questions on the basis of its tagging). Again, I won't push for that here, but that's what I was thinking when I made the tag edit earlier today.
